# Unable to test kotlin interface with Robolectric

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, robolectric

Currently, I am using a testing framework called Robolectric. And I was wondering what is the right way to test an interface to check the value and method for it. For example, In the following sample, I have an interface called TestInterface. And I wanted to test if this interface will work. So I set up like the following, by making the interface into an object. Is it a wrong way to do it ? Or is there a better approach? I'm not savvy with testing. So if there are some samples or hints, it will be so helpful. Thank you.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
    class MySampleTest {
    
      @Test
      fun `test mysample `() {
        val testName = "Test Name"
        val userInput = "User Input"
    
        val testResults = object : TestInterface {
          override val testValue: String
            get() = testName
    
          override fun createTest(input: String): String {
            return userInput+input
          }
        }.createTest(userInput)
    
        assertTrue(keyPair.verify(userInput, testResults))
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As we are not talking about UI, saying "test interface" confuses me. We can write tests for implementations only. Otherwise what we can test at all?

There should be one or more implementations in you project (if don't, why do even need this interface?), so you can test them.